# Is it possible to execute programs through url/js/php in "Google Chrome"?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, url, execute

I wanted to make my own "dashboard" with a local web-page, which could enable me to start programs through a link. I just wanted to know if there is any possibility to start a program or batch-file with the use of a url/ js-command/ php-command.

Comment: start a programme on the server yes, on a users computer: NO

Answer (score -3):

Make a .txt file, rename it to a .html file, put your code in, and use a button with `onclick="window.location.href='file path here'"` or a link to change the url.
For example:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='file path here!'">Program 1</button>
```

I know it works with .html files, and you can use script and php tags for js and php.

Comment: "I know it works with .html files." that's because your using a browser (which runs html) to run the script, try launching any other program like that

Comment: no. its simply security insanity to suggest this is the case.

Comment: this does not work it only prompts me to download the file

Comment: I use a computer running Windows 10. Maybe you have a different operating system.

Comment: Maybe we live in a different universe as well, because there's no way in our reality that any standard browser would allow this on any operating system.